# Do config files I'm referencing need to be in a project's home directory?

Tags: f#, config

I'm trying to store connection string and credentials data in a `.config` file.  I can't push the config with the connection/credentials to a repo; the config will be in a secure, synced folder that *isn't* the home directory.

I can store the connection/credentials in the `app.config` file in the home directory and access it with the `FSharp.Configuration` library:

```
type connection = AppSettings<"app.config">
```

but if I try to access a config in a different directory

```
open System.IO
open FSharp.Configuration

let baseDirectory = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
let baseDirectory' = Directory.GetParent(baseDirectory)
let configPath = "Tresor\app.config"
let fullConfigPath = Path.Combine(baseDirectory'.FullName, configPath)
type Settings = AppSettings<fullConfigPath>
```

the `fullConfigPath` errors out with

```
This is not a valid constant expression or custom attribute value.
```

Even if I try to use the yaml type provider

```
let yamlPath = "Tresor\Config.yaml"
let fullYamlPath = Path.Combine(baseDirectory'.FullName, yamlPath)
type Config = YamlConfig<FilePath = fullYamlPath>
```

I get a similar error for the `fullYamlPath`.

Is there a reason I can't access files outside of the home directory?  Am I constructing the file path correctly?

Comment: Arguments to type providers (in your case, `FilePath`) need to be compile-time constants (so either hardcoded strings or string literals).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** sorry, you're *probably* screwed, although there is a workaround using `SelectExecutableFile` that *might* work for you.

**Long answer:**
This is not how type providers work.

When you use a type provider to provide a type for you, the providing of the type happens at compile time (otherwise, what would be the point?). This means that all inputs that the type provider takes *also* need to be known at compile time. But in your code, the value of `fullConfigPath` or `fullYamlPath` isn't known until `Path.Combine` is executed, which will only happen at runtime.

The way it's *supposed* to work is, the type provider would take some "template" file (or database, or URL, or whatever it takes), which it can analyze and generate you the type from its contents. And then, later, at runtime, you would specify where to get the actual *data* from.

To reiterate, this all happens in two stages:

1. Data shape (aka "structure" aka "schema") at compile time.
2. Actual data at runtime.

This is how database providers usually work:

```
// Pseudocode. I don't have actual libraries handy.
type Db = SqlProvider<"Server=localhost;Database=my_development_db;Integrated Security=true">

let dbConnection = Db.OpenConnection Config.ProductionConnectionString
```

*Theoretically*, both `AppSettings` and `YamlConfig` providers would work somewhat similar:

```
type Config = AppSettings<"app.config">
let config = Config.OpenConfigFile "MyProgram.exe.config"
let someSetting = config.SomeSetting;
```

Unfortunately, this is not the case (for some reason).

`YamlConfig` provider doesn't have any way to load an alternate config file (it will always look for the one specified at compile time). But the `AppSettings` provider does give you [*some* control](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Configuration/AppSettingsProvider.html) via the `SelectExecutableFile` method. This is a static method that you can call in order to select the source of the data once and for all. And it doesn't take the config file path either, but only the `exe` file path, which it then [passes to `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration`](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Configuration/blob/master/src/FSharp.Configuration/AppSettingsProvider.fs#L20):

```
type Config = AppSettings<"app.config">
Config.SelectExecutableFile "MyProgram.exe"

let someSetting = Config.SomeSetting;
```

Which makes me unsure of how it would work with a web app.

I suppose this could give a **workaround**: call `SelectExecutableFile` and pass in the path to your config file sans the `.config` extension, that should work. But you also need to create a dummy file with the same name, but without the `.config` extension (which would stand in for the `exe` file), because the library [checks for its presence](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Configuration/blob/master/src/FSharp.Configuration/AppSettingsProvider.fs#L19).

**The bottom line is**, there is no support for what you're trying to do, and it's a shame, and I suggest you [file an issue](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Configuration/issues) about it.

Comment: For anyone coming across this now I wanted to point out that the YAML provider does now have a `Load` function on the type to load config at runtime.