# Connect to SQL database without the SQL type provider?

Tags: f#, type-providers

In reference [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362631/do-config-files-im-referencing-need-to-be-in-a-projects-home-directory), I need to share a connection string with coworkers without the connection string being pushed to our repository.  Using the F# SQL type provider forces me to "hardcode" the connection string in my code.  Although the *workaround* provided in the answer is promising, is there simply a way to connect to the dB without the type provider?

I already know the schema/structure of the dB; is there some other way I can connect?

Comment: *Using the F# SQL type provider forces me to "hardcode" the connection string in my code* this isn't true, you can pass a Connection String in at runtime.

Comment: @DaveShaw the _data_ connection string, you can pass in at runtime. But the _shape_ connection string has to be a constant in the source code.

Comment: do you simply need to change the connection string at run-time, or rather you don't want to make the connection string public on GitHub (neither the design time nor the run-time)? You could make a dll that contains the connection logic and push that your repo. If you don't to use a type provider you can always connect through ADO.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - that's only mostly true ;-). For instance, you could easily create an `EnvironmentVariableTypeProvider` which exposes all environment variables as literals, in which case you could use one as the argument to the SQL type provider.

Comment: How do you want to 'share' without pushing to the repo?

Comment: @CaringDev the connection string would be in a secure, synced folder located in the same relative location on all of our machines.

Comment: @Steven do you need the code to still compile if the synced folder is not present?

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is using the [EdmxFile](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/edmx.html) type provider:

```
#I "../packages/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/lib/net40"
#r "System.Data.Entity"
#r "FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll"

open FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

type DB = EdmxFile<"MyDB.edmx">

let c = new DB.Model.ModelContainer("runtimeConnectionString")

query { for e in c.MyEntitySet do select e.Id }
```

You can create the EDMX file in Visual Studio (from an existing DB or from scratch) by adding a new "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" item to a C# project and then moving it to the F# project. The designer functionality is then still available in the F# project.

Within the same [FSharp.Data.TypeProviders project](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/) there exist [DBML file](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/dbml.html), [SqlData](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/sqldata.html) and [SqlEntity](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/sqlentity.html) type providers. The latter two require compile time connection strings or names but also **support offline schema caching**. So you could *add the cache file to source control and then change the connection string*.

Another alternative would be to use any of the "live" type providers but point it to a source controlled MDF file:

```
let [<Literal>] LocalMDF =
    "Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=.\MyDataFile.mdf;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
```

If you are interested in issuing **plain SQL**, have a look at the [SQL Client](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/) type provider. It allows specifying the `.config` file used at design-time.

Apart from that, all "non-type-provider" (less convenient, less type-safe) standard .NET approaches can be used as well:

- ORMs (EF, NHibernate, Dapper, ...)
  Might require non-idiomatic, verbose F# to mimick C# classes
- ADO.NET
- Hand-Coding (SqlDataReader and associates)
- ...